# How to avoid an element changing its size and position?

Tags: css

I have three paragraphs elements. The three divided in three sections. I don't want none of them changing size or position. But I can't accomplish that. Maybe with flex can it be done. CSS is really hard to me, and someone told that is pretty common that.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Document</title>
      <style>
         body{
            background-color: rgb(238, 206, 236);
         }
         h1{
            text-align: center;
            background-color: rgb(250, 159, 250);
            color: purple;
            border-style: solid;
         }

         .row-container{
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: space-evenly;
            margin: 20px;
            margin-left: 50px;
            align-content: center;
         }
         .bilbo{
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            flex: 0 0 auto;
            background-color: rgb(238, 206, 236);
            color: black;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 7px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 0 5px;
            border-color: green;
            height: 300px;
            width: 350px;
            overflow-y: scroll;
         }
         #frodo{
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
         }
         button{
            vertical-align: top;
            height: 70px;
            width: 150px;
            background-color: #AAAAAA;
            border: 0.5px solid crimson;
            border-radius: 10px;
            padding: 20px;
            margin: 10px;
            text-decoration: none;
         }
         #penguin {
            color: white;
            border-radius: 25%;
            transition-property: border-radius,border,color,background-color;
            transition-duration: 0.1s;
            transition-timing-function: 0.1s;
            transition-delay: .3s;
            margin: 10px;
         }
         #penguin:hover {
            border-color: orange;
            color: white;
            background-color: black;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Libre y Singular</h1>
      <div class="row-container">
         <section class="bilbo">
            <p>Hace muchos años me topé con algo realmente novedoso para mí, algo que podría haber conocido cuando sólo tenía 6 años y que a esa edad hubiera podido sacarle un enorme provecho gracias a las CR Tronic 360 de la empresa de mi padre, Typographics. Este algo con el que me crucé fue el Software Libre. Me resultó algo maravilloso, era mi primer contacto con el Software. Esto es algo raro, nunca conocí en toda mi vida el software privativo. Durante muchísimos años tuve una Commodore Amiga 500, máquina con la conocí qué era un sistema operativo. La primera vez que usé el diskette que lo levantaba me quedé maravillado, cuando descubrí que podía jugar con un sintetizador de voz con el que podía simular una computadora que hablara por si misma algo similar ocurrió. Pero no, no conocí el software privativo con la Amiga, existía en ese momento el AmigaBasic y yo ni noticia.

            Hoy en día podría ser uno de los mejores programadores del mundo si hubiese conocido el software libre o el privativo en conjunto con las CR Tronic 360 de Typographics. En realidad, me equivoqué más arriba al decir que era la empresa de mi padre. Era la empresa de muchos hombres, muchos empleados. Los conocía a todos, pues yo iba a la empresa a verlo a él. Con algunos de ellos tenía más simpatía que otros, a los dos que más recuerdo son a Mítolo, "el pitufo"; a Umberto; a Eduardo Barone; a Sergio, "la gallina". Ellos hacían la empresa, más allá de sus fundadores y dueños.</p>
         </section>
         <section class="bilbo">

            <p>No recuerdo haber nunca haber interactuado con las máquinas, sólo recuerdo verlas en una oficina, eran inmensas. En la casa de mi madre tenía robots, o por lo menos uno. No conocía aún la relación entre ellos y las CR Tronic 360. Nadie me hablaba de software.

            Entonces, tratando de ir un poco al grano, qué es lo libre y singular. Es algo que pensé en oposición a la singularidad. Vendría a ser la singularidad libre. Con esto entiendo un tipo de tecnología, que podría ser interpretada como inteligencia artificial, si es que tal cosa existe, construida con software libre. Para mí todo empieza con un debate, y si muchos hablan acerca del peligro de la singularidad y la inteligencia artificial es siempre mejor empezar con esta instancia.</p>
         </section>
         <section class="bilbo">
            <p>Hace mucho años registré por primera vez el dominio Free-Singularity.org, empezó siendo un debate y un juego. Creé una cadena pequeña de páginas web conectadas con hipervínculos binarios. ¿Qué quiere decir esto? Mejor ver el ejemplo, me cuesta encontrar las palabras. Esa cadena llegaba a una canción sobre el número pi en un sitio web de video streaming. Ahora sé un poco más de diseño web y puedo apostar a captar tráfico, hacer crecer en serio este lugar.

            La cuestión es que mientras sigue mi debate, ya surgió lo que algunos consideran inteligencia artificial. Me estoy quedando en el tiempo. Por el momento mi apuesta es no usarla, estudiarla, pero sin tocarla, escuchar lo que dicen mis amigos, mis compañeros en la facultad, los profesores, mi familia y ese etcétera mimado por Umberto Eco.</p>
         </section>
      </div>
      <section id="frodo">
         <nav class="links">
            <a href="https://free-singularity.org/typographics.html"><button id="penguin">Typograhics</button></a>
            <a href="https://free-singularity.org/CR_Tronic_360.html"><button id="penguin">CR Tronic 360</button></a>
            <a href="https://free-singularity.org/Amiga500.html"><button id="penguin">Commodore Amiga 500</button></a>
         </nav>
      </section>
   </body>
</html>
```

I had change the code, sorry about that, but I need it to.
Now I have post the complete code of the website. Hope you can help me on this.

Here you can watch the problem online [click here](https://free-singularity.org/libreysingular41.html)

Comment: You are just telling me the mistakes. You are not been helpful. Ok, float: center does not exist, but I am not question in that. I need the paragraphs not changing size while shrinking the browser, and I don't want the third paragraph to be below.

Comment: Then check out flexbox or CSS-Grid on the parent of the `sections`. `inline-block` is your problem here.

Comment: Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: What do you mean by "changing size or position"?

Comment: I mean the size and position of the boxes of the columns.

Comment: Hey. Look at my answer, now it works perfectly with the complete code.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Flexbox on the `body` (or the parent of the `section` elements whatever that is) can do this.

Just ensure the `section` elements have `flex: 0 0 auto`;

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  display: flex;
}

section {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.bilbo {
  background-color: rgb(238, 206, 236);
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
  border-color: green;
  width: 150px;
  height: 425px;
  overflow: scroll;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<section class="bilbo">
  <p>Hace muchos años me topé con algo realmente novedoso para mí, algo que podría haber conocido cuando sólo tenía 6 años y que a esa edad hubiera podido sacarle un enorme provecho gracias a las CR Tronic 360 de la empresa de mi padre, Typographics. Este
    algo con el que me crucé fue el Software Libre. Me resultó algo maravilloso, era mi primer contacto con el Software. Esto es algo raro, nunca conocí en toda mi vida el software privativo. Durante muchísimos años tuve una Commodore Amiga 500, máquina
    con la conocí qué era un sistema operativo. La primera vez que usé el diskette que lo levantaba me quedé maravillado, cuando descubrí que podía jugar con un sintetizador de voz con el que podía simular una computadora que hablara por si misma algo
    similar ocurrió. Pero no, no conocí el software privativo con la Amiga, existía en ese momento el AmigaBasic y yo ni noticia.</p>

  <p>Hoy en día podría ser uno de los mejores programadores del mundo si hubiese conocido el software libre o el privativo en conjunto con las CR Tronic 360 de Typographics. En realidad, me equivoqué más arriba al decir que era la empresa de mi padre. Era
    la empresa de muchos hombres, muchos empleados. Los conocía a todos, pues yo iba a la empresa a verlo a él. Con algunos de ellos tenía más simpatía que otros, a los dos que más recuerdo son a Mítolo, "el pitufo"; a Umberto; a Eduardo Barone; a Sergio,
    "la gallina". Ellos hacían la empresa, más allá de sus fundadores y dueños.</p>
</section>
<section class="bilbo">

  <p>No recuerdo haber nunca haber interactuado con las máquinas, sólo recuerdo verlas en una oficina, eran inmensas. En la casa de mi madre tenía robots, o por lo menos uno. No conocía aún la relación entre ellos y las CR Tronic 360. Nadie me hablaba de
    software.</p>

  <p>Entonces, tratando de ir un poco al grano, qué es lo libre y singular. Es algo que pensé en oposición a la singularidad. Vendría a ser la singularidad libre. Con esto entiendo un tipo de tecnología, que podría ser interpretada como inteligencia artificial,
    si es que tal cosa existe, construida con software libre. Para mí todo empieza con un debate, y si muchos hablan acerca del peligro de la singularidad y la inteligencia artificial es siempre mejor empezar con esta instancia.</p>
</section>
<section class="bilbo">
  <p>Hace mucho años registré por primera vez el dominio Free-Singularity.org, empezó siendo un debate y un juego. Creé una cadena pequeña de páginas web conectadas con hipervínculos binarios. ¿Qué quiere decir esto? Mejor ver el ejemplo, me cuesta encontrar
    las palabras. Esa cadena llegaba a una canción sobre el número pi en un sitio web de video streaming. Ahora sé un poco más de diseño web y puedo apostar a captar tráfico, hacer crecer en serio este lugar.</p>

  <p>La cuestión es que mientras sigue mi debate, ya surgió lo que algunos consideran inteligencia artificial. Me estoy quedando en el tiempo. Por el momento mi apuesta es no usarla, estudiarla, pero sin tocarla, escuchar lo que dicen mis amigos, mis compañeros
    en la facultad, los profesores, mi familia y ese etcétera mimado por Umberto Eco.</p>
</section>
</div>
```

Comment: I had changed the code, now it is complete.

Comment: I don't know why, but this code does not work properly. Maybe it is because I changed the code of the question. Maybe you change your answer @Paulie_D . Sorry about the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `display: flex;` and `position: absolute;` attributes for font sizes or margin gap you can use the vh unit (there are certain converters for px to vh)

Example Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <script>

        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            const clock = document.querySelector(".time");
            const date = document.querySelector(".date");

            function getTime() {
                const time = new Date();
                const hours = time.getHours();
                const minutes = time.getMinutes();
                const seconds = time.getSeconds();
                const day = time.getDate();
                const month = time.getMonth();
                const year = time.getFullYear();

                clock.innerHTML = `${hours < 10 ? `${hours}` : hours}:${minutes < 10 ? `0${minutes}` : minutes}:${seconds < 10 ? `0${seconds}` : seconds}`;
                date.innerHTML = `${day < 10 ? `${day}` : day}/${month < 10 ? `0${month + 1}` : month + 1}/${year}`;
            }

            getTime()
            setInterval(getTime, 1000);
            
            window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
                let data = event.data
                if (data.type == "updateInfos") {
                    document.querySelector("#id").innerText = data.id
                    document.querySelector("#money").innerText = new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(data.money)
                    document.querySelector("#blackmoney").innerText = new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(data.blackmoney)
                    document.querySelector("#job").innerText = data.job
                } else if (data.type == "updateVehicleInfos") {
                    document.querySelector(".kmph").innerText = data.kmph
                    document.querySelector(".lock").style.background = data.lock ? "#FF0000" : "rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.23)"
                    document.querySelector(".fuel").style.background = data.fuel < 20 ? "#FF0000" : "rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.23)"
                } else if (data.action == "showSpedo") {
                    document.querySelector(".vehicle-infos").style.display = "flex"
                } else if (data.action == "hideSpedo") {
                    document.querySelector(".vehicle-infos").style.display = "none"
                }
            })
        })

    </script>
    <body>
        <div class="time-date">
            <div class="clock">
                <svg class="svg22" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="22" height="22" viewBox="0 0 22 22" fill="none">
                    <path d="M11 21C16.5228 21 21 16.5228 21 11C21 5.47715 16.5228 1 11 1C5.47715 1 1 5.47715 1 11C1 16.5228 5.47715 21 11 21Z" stroke="#F8F8F8" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M14 15L11.586 12.586C11.2109 12.211 11.0001 11.7024 11 11.172V5" stroke="#F8F8F8" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                </svg>
            </div>
            <div class="text">
                <div class="time">18:56</div>
                <div class="date">18/06/2020</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="account-infos">
            <div class="text-account">
                <span id="id">1</span>
                <div class="item">
                    <svg class="svg24" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path d="M20 4H4C2.897 4 2 4.897 2 6V18C2 19.103 2.897 20 4 20H20C21.103 20 22 19.103 22 18V6C22 4.897 21.103 4 20 4ZM8.715 8C9.866 8 10.715 8.849 10.715 10C10.715 11.151 9.866 12 8.715 12C7.564 12 6.715 11.151 6.715 10C6.715 8.849 7.563 8 8.715 8ZM12.43 16H5V15.535C5 14.162 6.676 12.75 8.715 12.75C10.754 12.75 12.43 14.162 12.43 15.535V16ZM19 15H15V13H19V15ZM19 11H14V9H19V11Z" fill="#F8F8F8"/>
                    </svg>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-account">
                <span id="money">999.999.999.999</span>
                <div class="item">
                    <svg width="35" height="35" viewBox="0 0 35 35" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path d="M17.6667 28.333C11.224 28.333 6 23.109 6 16.6663C6 10.2236 11.224 4.99967 17.6667 4.99967C24.1094 4.99967 29.3333 10.2236 29.3333 16.6663C29.3333 23.109 24.1094 28.333 17.6667 28.333ZM19.3203 18.5465C19.4349 18.5465 19.5286 18.4528 19.5286 18.3382V17.6299C19.5286 17.5153 19.4349 17.4215 19.3203 17.4215H15.7786C15.7708 17.307 15.7708 17.1846 15.7708 17.0622V16.1247H19.3177C19.4323 16.1247 19.526 16.0309 19.526 15.9163V15.208C19.526 15.0934 19.4323 14.9997 19.3177 14.9997H15.9193C16.3177 13.3851 17.5156 12.432 19.2995 12.432C19.8177 12.432 20.2656 12.4632 20.6484 12.5387C20.776 12.5648 20.8958 12.4658 20.8958 12.3356V11.221C20.8958 11.1221 20.8255 11.0387 20.7292 11.0179C20.3151 10.9294 19.8359 10.8851 19.2891 10.8851C16.4297 10.8851 14.5234 12.4163 14.0755 14.9997H13.2917C13.1771 14.9997 13.0833 15.0934 13.0833 15.208V15.9163C13.0833 16.0309 13.1771 16.1247 13.2917 16.1247H13.9714V17.0856C13.9714 17.2002 13.9714 17.3148 13.9792 17.4189H13.2917C13.1771 17.4189 13.0833 17.5127 13.0833 17.6273V18.3356C13.0833 18.4502 13.1771 18.5439 13.2917 18.5439H14.1172C14.6302 20.9971 16.513 22.4476 19.2891 22.4476C19.8333 22.4476 20.3151 22.3981 20.7292 22.307C20.8255 22.2861 20.8932 22.2028 20.8932 22.1038V20.9893H20.8958C20.8958 20.8564 20.776 20.7601 20.6458 20.7861C20.263 20.8617 19.8177 20.9007 19.2995 20.9007C17.5964 20.9007 16.4245 20.0283 15.9766 18.5465H19.3203Z" fill="#05FF00"/>
                    </svg>    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-account">
                <span id="blackmoney">999.999.999.999</span>
                <div class="item">
                    <svg width="35" height="35" viewBox="0 0 35 35" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path d="M17.6667 28.333C11.224 28.333 6 23.109 6 16.6663C6 10.2236 11.224 4.99967 17.6667 4.99967C24.1094 4.99967 29.3333 10.2236 29.3333 16.6663C29.3333 23.109 24.1094 28.333 17.6667 28.333ZM19.3203 18.5465C19.4349 18.5465 19.5286 18.4528 19.5286 18.3382V17.6299C19.5286 17.5153 19.4349 17.4215 19.3203 17.4215H15.7786C15.7708 17.307 15.7708 17.1846 15.7708 17.0622V16.1247H19.3177C19.4323 16.1247 19.526 16.0309 19.526 15.9163V15.208C19.526 15.0934 19.4323 14.9997 19.3177 14.9997H15.9193C16.3177 13.3851 17.5156 12.432 19.2995 12.432C19.8177 12.432 20.2656 12.4632 20.6484 12.5387C20.776 12.5648 20.8958 12.4658 20.8958 12.3356V11.221C20.8958 11.1221 20.8255 11.0387 20.7292 11.0179C20.3151 10.9294 19.8359 10.8851 19.2891 10.8851C16.4297 10.8851 14.5234 12.4163 14.0755 14.9997H13.2917C13.1771 14.9997 13.0833 15.0934 13.0833 15.208V15.9163C13.0833 16.0309 13.1771 16.1247 13.2917 16.1247H13.9714V17.0856C13.9714 17.2002 13.9714 17.3148 13.9792 17.4189H13.2917C13.1771 17.4189 13.0833 17.5127 13.0833 17.6273V18.3356C13.0833 18.4502 13.1771 18.5439 13.2917 18.5439H14.1172C14.6302 20.9971 16.513 22.4476 19.2891 22.4476C19.8333 22.4476 20.3151 22.3981 20.7292 22.307C20.8255 22.2861 20.8932 22.2028 20.8932 22.1038V20.9893H20.8958C20.8958 20.8564 20.776 20.7601 20.6458 20.7861C20.263 20.8617 19.8177 20.9007 19.2995 20.9007C17.5964 20.9007 16.4245 20.0283 15.9766 18.5465H19.3203Z" fill="#FF0000"/>
                    </svg>                        
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-account">
                <span id="job">Mechaniker</span>
                <div class="item">
                    <svg class="svg28" width="28" height="28" viewBox="0 0 28 28" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path d="M24.8309 9.65506L17.8883 8.64608L14.7848 2.35428C14.7 2.18202 14.5606 2.04256 14.3883 1.9578C13.9563 1.74452 13.4313 1.92225 13.2153 2.35428L10.1117 8.64608L3.16916 9.65506C2.97776 9.68241 2.80276 9.77264 2.66877 9.90936C2.50679 10.0758 2.41753 10.2998 2.42061 10.5321C2.42369 10.7644 2.51884 10.9859 2.68518 11.148L7.70822 16.0453L6.5215 22.9605C6.49368 23.1214 6.51148 23.2868 6.57289 23.4381C6.6343 23.5894 6.73687 23.7204 6.86896 23.8163C7.00105 23.9123 7.15738 23.9693 7.32021 23.9809C7.48305 23.9925 7.64589 23.9582 7.79025 23.882L14 20.6172L20.2098 23.882C20.3793 23.9723 20.5762 24.0023 20.7649 23.9695C21.2406 23.8875 21.5606 23.4363 21.4785 22.9605L20.2918 16.0453L25.3149 11.148C25.4516 11.014 25.5418 10.839 25.5692 10.6476C25.643 10.1691 25.3094 9.72616 24.8309 9.65506Z" fill="#FFC700"/>
                    </svg>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="vehicle-infos">
            <div class="box lock">
                <svg class="svg47" width="47" height="47" viewBox="0 0 47 47" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path d="M39.1666 23.5C39.1666 21.3399 37.41 19.5833 35.25 19.5833H33.2916V13.7083C33.2916 8.3092 28.8991 3.91666 23.5 3.91666C18.1009 3.91666 13.7083 8.3092 13.7083 13.7083V19.5833H11.75C9.58994 19.5833 7.83331 21.3399 7.83331 23.5V39.1667C7.83331 41.3267 9.58994 43.0833 11.75 43.0833H35.25C37.41 43.0833 39.1666 41.3267 39.1666 39.1667V23.5ZM17.625 13.7083C17.625 10.4692 20.2609 7.83332 23.5 7.83332C26.7391 7.83332 29.375 10.4692 29.375 13.7083V19.5833H17.625V13.7083Z" fill="#FF0000"/>
                </svg>
            </div>
            <div class="box fuel">
                <svg class="svg41" width="41" height="41" viewBox="0 0 41 41" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path d="M2.5625 5.125C2.5625 3.76577 3.10245 2.4622 4.06358 1.50108C5.0247 0.539954 6.32827 0 7.6875 0L23.0625 0C24.4217 0 25.7253 0.539954 26.6864 1.50108C27.6475 2.4622 28.1875 3.76577 28.1875 5.125V25.625C29.5467 25.625 30.8503 26.165 31.8114 27.1261C32.7725 28.0872 33.3125 29.3908 33.3125 30.75V32.0312C33.3125 32.3711 33.4475 32.6969 33.6878 32.9372C33.9281 33.1775 34.2539 33.3125 34.5938 33.3125C34.9336 33.3125 35.2594 33.1775 35.4997 32.9372C35.74 32.6969 35.875 32.3711 35.875 32.0312V20.5H34.5938C34.2539 20.5 33.9281 20.365 33.6878 20.1247C33.4475 19.8844 33.3125 19.5586 33.3125 19.2188V11.2109C33.3125 10.8711 33.4475 10.5452 33.6878 10.305C33.9281 10.0647 34.2539 9.92969 34.5938 9.92969H38.4247C38.3965 8.70994 38.2889 7.63881 37.9096 6.79831C37.7066 6.3096 37.3529 5.89844 36.9 5.62469C36.4285 5.34281 35.711 5.125 34.5938 5.125C34.2539 5.125 33.9281 4.99001 33.6878 4.74973C33.4475 4.50945 33.3125 4.18356 33.3125 3.84375C33.3125 3.50394 33.4475 3.17805 33.6878 2.93777C33.9281 2.69749 34.2539 2.5625 34.5938 2.5625C36.039 2.5625 37.2434 2.84437 38.212 3.4235C39.1934 4.00775 39.8366 4.83544 40.2466 5.74769C41.0026 7.42613 41 9.50175 41 11.0802V19.2188C41 19.5586 40.865 19.8844 40.6247 20.1247C40.3844 20.365 40.0586 20.5 39.7188 20.5H38.4375V32.0312C38.4375 33.0507 38.0325 34.0284 37.3117 34.7492C36.5909 35.47 35.6132 35.875 34.5938 35.875C33.5743 35.875 32.5966 35.47 31.8758 34.7492C31.155 34.0284 30.75 33.0507 30.75 32.0312V30.75C30.75 30.0704 30.48 29.4186 29.9995 28.938C29.5189 28.4575 28.8671 28.1875 28.1875 28.1875V38.4375H29.4688C29.8086 38.4375 30.1345 38.5725 30.3747 38.8128C30.615 39.0531 30.75 39.3789 30.75 39.7188C30.75 40.0586 30.615 40.3844 30.3747 40.6247C30.1345 40.865 29.8086 41 29.4688 41H1.28125C0.941441 41 0.61555 40.865 0.375269 40.6247C0.134988 40.3844 0 40.0586 0 39.7188C0 39.3789 0.134988 39.0531 0.375269 38.8128C0.61555 38.5725 0.941441 38.4375 1.28125 38.4375H2.5625V5.125ZM8.96875 5.125C8.62894 5.125 8.30305 5.25999 8.06277 5.50027C7.82249 5.74055 7.6875 6.06644 7.6875 6.40625V19.2188C7.6875 19.5586 7.82249 19.8844 8.06277 20.1247C8.30305 20.365 8.62894 20.5 8.96875 20.5H21.7812C22.1211 20.5 22.447 20.365 22.6872 20.1247C22.9275 19.8844 23.0625 19.5586 23.0625 19.2188V6.40625C23.0625 6.06644 22.9275 5.74055 22.6872 5.50027C22.447 5.25999 22.1211 5.125 21.7812 5.125H8.96875Z" fill="#FF0000"/>
                </svg>                    
            </div>
            <div class="kmph">199KMH</div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <style>
        body {
            background: #000;
        }

        .time-date {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: flex-start;
            align-items: center;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            margin: 1vh;
            gap: 1vh
        }

        .account-infos {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: flex-end;
            align-items: flex-end;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            margin: 1vh;
            gap: 1vh;
            flex-direction: column;
        }

        .vehicle-infos {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: flex-end;
            align-items: flex-end;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
            margin: 1vh;
            gap: 1vh;
            flex-direction: row;
        }

        .item {
            width: 3.7037vh;
            height: 3.7037vh;
            flex-shrink: 0;
            background: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.23);
            border-radius: 100%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .kmph {
            width: 23.6111vh;
            height: 7.8704vh;
            flex-shrink: 0;
            border-radius: 1.8519vh;
            background: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.23);
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 3.2407vh;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 100;
            color: #FFF;
        }

        .box {
            width: 7.8704vh;
            height: 7.8704vh;
            flex-shrink: 0;
            background: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.23);
            border-radius: 1.8519vh;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        svg {
            width: 3.2407vh;
            height: 3.2407vh;
        }

        .svg24 {
            width: 2.2222vh;
            height: 2.2222vh;
        }

        .svg28 {
            width: 2.5926vh;
            height: 2.5926vh;
        }

        .svg22 {
            width: 2.037vh;
            height: 2.037vh;
        }

        .svg47 {
            width: 4.3519vh;
            height: 4.3519vh;
        }

        .svg41 {
            width: 3.7963vh;
            height: 3.763vh;
        }

        .clock {
            width: 3.7037vh;
            height: 3.7037vh;
            flex-shrink: 0;
            background: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.23);
            border-radius: 100%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .text {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: flex-start;
            align-items: flex-start;
            gap: 0;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 1.3889vh;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 100;
            color: #FFF;
        }

        .text-account {
            display: flex;
            /* flex-direction: column; */
            justify-content: flex-start;
            align-items: center;
            gap: 1vh;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 1.8519vh;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 100;
            color: #FFF;
        }


        .date {
            opacity: 0.7;
        }

        .kmmph {
            width: 15.9375rem;
            height: 5.3125rem;
            flex-shrink: 0;
            border-radius: 1.25rem;
            background: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.23);
        }
    </style>
</html>
```

By far not the best example but works perfectly fine

Comment: Your answer has nothing to do with the question.